# how can i use ejs variables from other file

Tags: javascript, ejs

i am trying to do spa and i am kind of stacking in this code

```
import AbstractView from "./AbstractView.js";

export default class extends AbstractView {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params);
        this.setTitle("Profile");
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <main>
                <center>
                <div class="profile-page">
                    <img src="" alt="astro" style="border-radius: 50%;margin-right: 15px;">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 20px;"><%= client.user.username %></h1>
                    <h3>Select server to start managing</h3>
                    <br>
                    <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button class="button_support">Support</button></a>
                </div>
                </center>
            </main>
        `;
    }
}
```

This is taking from github source and what i am trying to do is i want to show ejs variable in the html and this what happen:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2PO0.png)
if you have any question about the code ask and a will text you back thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to the `client` object? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: This is not the bot side this is the website side i am trying to move this code to ejs with it variables

Comment: Can you assign to a js variable like `const username = <%= client.user.username %>` and then use inside the template literal like `${username}`?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see where you are rendering from with ejs, I can't see much;
These are some key things to check:
Make sure the variable in the ejs file matches very well with what you have rendered in the server. It's case sensitive and you should in fact copy and paste. Also, don't keep those variables or const in quotes ", it's also a common mistake;

It will be very helpful if you can share the exact error message you are getting.